# Net framework version in .runsettings file

Tags: c#, mstest

I want to poin my unit test .runsettings file to .Net 4.6.1 and I have tried to specify like below,

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework461</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

but the run time is not able to identify it and throwing below error,

Error:

> Invalid settings 'RunConfiguration'. Invalid value 'Framework461' specified for 'TargetFrameworkVersion'.

Comment: Which error does the runtime throw?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Maybe you don't have 4.6.1 installed on your machine? I guess you need the .NET SDK, not only the .NET runtime.

Comment: @UweKeim yes I do have 4.6.1

Comment: It is documented pretty well, valid choices for this setting are Framework35, Framework40 or Framework45.  The distinction between the latter 2 are a bit mysterious, probably used for error checking.  Regardless, you'll always run on the *installed* version of the framework, there can only ever be one 4.x version.

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan, I have the same issue, is the issue fixed, could you post the solution if so?